# Scraping data from Instagram

Tags: javascript, php, instagram, instagram-api, yql

I actually just need the **followers count** of a public account,
for example https://www.instagram.com/kygomusic/

The new Instagram's API rules are very strict (and discussed):
**It's now impossible to access public content for most of common apps. You need a public_content scope that is not granted to normal app (?!)**

> public_content: This permission (public_content) is only granted to
>   apps that enable brands, advertisers, broadcasters and publishers to
>   discover public content. We do not grant access to apps that do not
>   fall into these categories. Please review our documentation
>   (https://www.instagram.com/developer/review) for more information.

### So I decided to scrape the data from Instagram

An option is to use **file_get_contents()** (PHP) and it works but it loads all the site from my server and it's pretty heavy. So my first idea was to use **YQL**. I use it for Twitter and works well, but when I scrape data from Instagram I get **nothing**:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Fkygomusic%2F'&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took a look into the page you submitted, it's not that heavy, considering that you won't load images or process js. While inspecting I found out that they have a json where they store their data.

.... "followed_by": {"count": 924725}

I didn't had time to test this, but it should work, or at least you get the point of using it. CURL may be a better option because it can handle multithreaded requests.

```
$url = 'https://www.instagram.com/kygomusic/';
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$count = 0;
if(preg_match('#followed_by": {"count": (.*?)}#', $str, $match)) {
     $count = $match[1]; // get the count from Regex pattern
} echo $count;
```

Comment: You can also improve the speed, even if single threaded with curl. Depending on your server ghz and bandwidth, you could tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this library: https://github.com/raiym/instagram-php-scraper you can get count of followers and follows and get almost any public info shared on instagram without auth.

It is based on JSON responses that I and community have found and it is pretty lightweight

Comment: Can you please describe more of it's functionalities?. Could it be used to grab latest photos with a given limit ?

Comment: Yes. `$medias = Instagram::getMedias('kevin', 150);`

Comment: Giving me an error when I included the namespace, saying Class 'Unirest\Request' not found in... What could be the problem ??

Comment: OK.... I managed to get that solved, However now I'm getting Uncaught exception 'Unirest\Exception' with message 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' in....